# Program to find determinant of a n x n matrix not working

Tags: python, recursion, matrix, determinants

when i give a 3X3 matrix as input,it returns index error at line: m[0][0]*m[1][1]-m[0][1]*m[1][0]

```
import copy

def matrixdeterminant(m):
    if len(m)==1:
        return m[0]
    elif len(m)==2:
        return m[0][0]*m[1][1]-m[0][1]*m[1][0]
    else:
        matrixdeterminantlist=copy.deepcopy(m)
        determinantlist=[]
        m.pop(0)

        for i in range(len(matrixdeterminantlist[0])):
            for j in range(len(m)):
                m[j].pop(i)
            determinantlist.append(matrixdeterminantlist[0][i]*matrixdeterminant(m)*(-1)**(i+2))

            m=copy.deepcopy(matrixdeterminantlist)
   
    return sum(determinantlist)
```

Comment: Please include the 3x3 matrix that you tried this on, and the exact error message.

Comment: the 3x3 matrix i gave in the function call=m = [[8,4,2], [2,-3,5], [1,4,9]]

Comment: I didn't test your code, but I'm guessing `if len(m)==1: return m[0]` should instead be `if len(m)==1: return m[0][0]`

Comment: error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)
Step through your code. You're popping elements from rows, and popping entire rows. That's probably leaving you with fewer rows/columns than you expect. Try slicing instead of popping to get sub-arrays

Comment: @stef i wud make that change however,that isn't the error since it shud never go that if condition for 3x3 matrix

Comment: @PranavHosangadi i am popping columns temporiraly to find the cofactor of the element

Comment: I added a `print(m)` at the start of your function. I get this: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] | [[5, 6], [8, 9]] | 
[[1, 3], [4, 6], [7, 9]] | 
[[6], [9]]` Then error. Clearly, `len(m) == 2` but there aren't 2 columns

Comment: Don't pop from `m`. pop from your copy. Reassigning a different value to the name `m` later doesn't affect the `m` that you originally modified.

Comment: when m becomes [[5,6],[8,9]] shouldn't it go to the elif condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue I can spot: you wrote `return m[0]` rather than `return m[0][0]` for the case where `len(m) == 1`.

If `m` is a 1x1 matrix, then `m` looks something like `[[x]]`, and you want to return `x`, not `[x]`, so you have to return `m[0][0]`, not `m[0]`.

Another important issue in your code is the way you pop elements from `m` and then try to restore `m` from its copies. This is overly complicated and you restore `m` wrongly inside the loop, so at some points the dimensions of `m` are all screwed-up. I recommend to avoid using `.pop` at all, and instead, build the submatrices using [**list comprehensions**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Here is a simplified version:

```py
def matrixdeterminant(m):
    if len(m)==1:
        return m[0][0]
    elif len(m)==2:
        return m[0][0]*m[1][1]-m[0][1]*m[1][0]
    else:
        determinantlist=[]
        sign = 1
        for i in range(len(m)):
            submatrix = [row[1:] for j,row in enumerate(m) if j != i]
            minor = matrixdeterminant(submatrix)
            determinantlist.append(sign * m[i][0] * minor)
            sign *= -1
        return sum(determinantlist)
```

And here is yet another version:

```py
from itertools import cycle

def matdet(m):
    if len(m) == 1:
        return m[0][0]
    else:
        return sum(
            s * mj[0] * matdet([row[1:] for i,row in enumerate(m) if i != j])
            for s,(j,mj) in zip(cycle([1,-1]), enumerate(m))
        )
```

Once it's producing numerical values instead of error messages, I strongly encourage you to test your determinant function by comparing its output on big random matrices, against the output of a matrix determinant function from a standard python module such as `numpy` or `sympy` or `scipy`:

- [numpy: `numpy.linalg.det`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html);
- [scipy: `scipy.linalg.det`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.det.html#scipy.linalg.det);
- [sympy: `Matrix.det`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html#determinant).

Comment: it shud never go to 1x1 matrix tho how wud it,len(m) shud never become 1 for a 3x3 matrix

Comment: @Codingbeginner Yes. The main problem for a 3x3 matrix seems to be the way you `.pop` many elements from `m` in a for-loop. Then you try to restore `m` from the copies that you've made, but it doesn't quite work correctly.

Comment: @Codingbeginner The error is in the way you pop from `m`. If you want to see, print the matrix at each iteration of your for-loop, and you'll notice it's not the correct shape.

Comment: thanks for your answer but idk how enumerate and all works

Comment: @Codingbeginner I recommend you read [the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). You can also read the documentation for [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and for [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), and for [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) although this last one is less important.